# Why is VBA code slowing down when processing larger tables

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, performance

I got problem with one of my subroutines, which job is to convert any passed ListObject (ussually generated by powerquery) into multiple MySQL queries, then send them to database. Queries and progress are shown on userform, that refresh with every query. My problem is that for some reason with some large tables, code starts out very quickly, but at some point it instantly slows down to fraction of speed it started and excel ram usage is increasing by +-1MB/s while running, and after code finish, it stays there.

With smaller tables (low column count, or small values in cells) it can process tens of thousands rows very fast without slowing, but problem comes with some large tables (either higher column count, or big values in cells, for ex. long strings etc...) after like 3k rows.

This sub is responsible for looping thru table, and building insert queries, then every few rows (depending on query length) calls function, that can send any query into selected DB. The problem is in "For i" loop, but i including whole code here.

```
Public Sub UploadniPayload(DBtabulka As String, Zdroj As ListObject, Optional Databaze As String = "tesu")
    If ErrorMode = False Then On Error Resume Next

    Dim Prikaz As String, Radek As String, Payload As String, i As Long, x As Long, PocetRadku As Long, PocetSloupcu As Long, DBsloupce As Long
        
        Call VyplnNetInfo(DBIP)
        AutoUploader.loading_sql.Value = 0
        PocetRadku = Zdroj.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
        PocetSloupcu = Zdroj.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count
        DBsloupce = DBPocetSloupcu(DBtabulka, Databaze)

        If JeTabulkaPrazdna(Zdroj) = False Then
            If (Zdroj.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count + 1) = DBsloupce Then

               'PROBLEM APPEARING IN THIS LOOP
                For i = 1 To PocetRadku
                    For x = 1 To PocetSloupcu
                        If x <= 0 Then Exit For
                        If x = 1 Then
                            Payload = "'','" & Zdroj.DataBodyRange(i, x).Text & "'"
                        Else
                            Payload = Payload & ",'" & Zdroj.DataBodyRange(i, x).Text & "'"
                        End If
                    Next x
                    Radek = "(" & Payload & ")"
                    If Prikaz <> vbNullString Then Prikaz = Prikaz & ", " & Radek Else Prikaz = Radek
                    If i = PocetRadku Or Len(Prikaz) > 2500 Then
                        AutoUploader.loading_sql.Value = i / PocetRadku
                        AutoUploader.txtStatus.Caption = "Zpracovávám " & i & "/" & PocetRadku & " řádků"
                        Prikaz = "INSERT INTO `" & Databaze & "`.`" & DBtabulka & "` VALUES " & Prikaz
                        Call PrikazSQL(Prikaz, Databaze)
                        Prikaz = vbNullString
                        Payload = vbNullString
                    End If
                Next i
    
            Else
                Call Zaloguj("System", "Error - počet sloupců v " & Zdroj.Name & " (" & PocetSloupcu & "+1 ID) nesouhlasí s počtem sloupců v " & DBtabulka & "(" & DBsloupce & ")", False)
            End If
        Else
            Call Zaloguj("System", "Error - pokus o upload prázdné tabulky (" & Zdroj.Name & ") do DB (" & DBtabulka & ")", False)
        End If
        
        If AutoUploader.chb_Uklizecka.Value = True Then Call VycistiTabulku(Zdroj)
End Sub
```

And this is my function responsible for sending queries into database.
Sometimes i use it for pulling single value from database, so it acts as string, but when i need only insert, i just using Call. DBIP, DBUser and DBPass are global variables.

```
Public Function PrikazSQL(ByRef Prikaz As String, Optional Databaze As String = "tesu") As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    
    AutoUploader.IconDirectSQL.BackColor = vbGreen
    AutoUploader.txtKUK.Value = Prikaz
    'If ErrorMode = True Then Call Zasifruj
    DoEvents
    
    Dim Pripojeni As ADODB.Connection, RS As ADODB.Recordset
    Set Pripojeni = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
        Pripojeni.Open "" & _
            "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 UNICODE Driver}" & _
            ";SERVER=" & DBIP & _
            ";DATABASE=" & Databaze & _
            ";USER=" & DBUser & _
            ";PASSWORD=" & DBPass & _
            ";Option=3"
        With RS
            .CursorLocation = adUseClient
            .LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic
            .Open Prikaz, Pripojeni
            .ActiveConnection = Nothing
        End With
        Pripojeni.Close
        Set Pripojeni = Nothing
         If RS.Fields.Count > 0 Then PrikazSQL = RS(0)
        Set RS = Nothing
        AutoUploader.IconDirectSQL.BackColor = vbWhite
        DoEvents
Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    RS.ActiveConnection = Nothing
    If Not Pripojeni Is Nothing Then
        Pripojeni.Close
        Set Pripojeni = Nothing
    End If
    If RS.Fields.Count > 0 Then PrikazSQL = RS(0)
    Set RS = Nothing
    AutoUploader.IconDirectSQL.BackColor = vbWhite
    DoEvents
    Call Debuger("ERROR:" & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "QUERY:" & vbCrLf & Prikaz, "PrikazSQL")

End Function
```

Code above is only part of the autonomous bot, on start it apply these settings:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

DoEvents is used only for refreshing userform, instead of repaint.

I try to unload any object or variable, that i dont need, but i think i am missing something important. Any other part of code runs fine. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: In the for loop you are concatenating an increasingly longer string. String operations in VBA are very ineffective and involves a lot of copying of data in memory.

Comment: Hi, thanks for comment. That string is reseted after 2500 characters. 
It only slow down after few thousands iterations, but string lengts is ussually +- same in every iteration, so that should not be problem in my oppinion.

Comment: Does your ODBC MySQL driver support connection pooling? How long does it take it to acquire the first, second, 3rd, 20th connection? Use the `Timer` function to get a numeric value representing the number of seconds since midnight, e.g. `tStart = Timer`; then you can then `Debug.Print tStart - Timer` to track how long it takes to run a chunk of code and narrow it down to a particular bottleneck. I haven't looked in details, but if the amount of data involved per iteration isn't constant, then it's normal that processing time scales along with the data being processed.

Comment: PrikazSQL creates a new connection every time it is called along with a recordset object, which is not particularly efficient. Recordset is not needed for inserts.

Comment: Consider sending an actual `INSERT` statement through `Connection.Execute` instead of manipulating a recordset, and if your driver doesn't support connection pooling then having a new connection every time is going to cost a lot, especially on a slower network.

Comment: I know that using recordset every time isnt best option, but i using this function both ways, sometimes i want reply, and sometimes i dont. Even with inserts i need to be able to read reply in case of error (for debuger, which export query and error to text file).
As for which part of code is slow, i see it on userform when it start to slow down. Its same code, starts out very fast, but after big number of iterations the problem appears. 
As for connection pooling... tbh i have no idea, but every connection is closed before opening new one, but i will dig into this just to be sure.

Comment: I tried pull half a milion values from database to test PrikazSQL, but it was done in matter of seconds. The DB is very fast, and its on same company network, so connectivity isnt problem either.

Also.. just tried to reverse FOR loop to start from end of the table and go up, and it start immediatly slow and gradually getting faster... seems like the problem is in accesing DataBodyRange, when row adress is high or something like that.
Even tried to use not DBR but activecell loop with offsets, but no change :(

Comment: Please show us the generated SQL queries.

Comment: Sorry, cannot post actually queries, they contain very personal info of our customers, but INSERTS are formated like this:

INSERT INTO `database`.`table` VALUES ('R1C1','R1C2','R1C3','R1C4','R1C5'), ('R2C1','R2C2','R2C3','R2C4','R2C5'), ('R3C1','R3C2','R3C3','R3C4','R3C5')

Comment: Have you tested single insert like NSERT INTO database.table VALUES ('R1C1','R1C2','R1C3','R1C4','R1C5') instead of multiple values?